# How can I repost my unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

I posted a question at non working hours. I might need to repost it for it to show up among the latest questions. Is it possible to repost my question?

Comment: Sorry no, if you do it will be closed as a duplicate of your original. You can draw attention to your original question by editing it to improve it: include additional information, details of what you've tried since you posted it, and images with hand-drawn red circles are always popular :P

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no need to repost your question. Provided it was well-written, it will be found eventually by people seeking unanswered questions.

If you feel you can improve your question, feel free to edit it and add additional information that may help people answer. Consider also whether you've chosen a good selection of tags, as this can influence people's interest in your question.

If you still get no answers, you could consider adding a bounty, if you have sufficient privilege (75+) to do so.

Comment: you could always update the question slightly and then it will get on the recently posted board.

Comment: Although, refrain from making updates *just for the sake of putting your question at the top*. Updates should, in fact, update something.